# Why am I getting an if: Expression syntax error in ~/.profile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax, profile

I am getting an `'if: Expression syntax'` error in my `.profile` when I try to `source ~/.profile` it. What am I doing wrong? [.profile file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsizU.png)

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Go therefore I've removed that tag from the question. Also you should avoid using images, especially links to images, instead you should use text, including code, whereever possible.

Comment: the `if` block from that linked image looks ok, and [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) confirms no issues with the `if` block; can you confirm you're running under the `bash` shell? could there be another `if` block elsewhere in `~/.profile`, or in a subordinate script? if you modify the script like such: `echo "1"; tty -s; if ... fi; echo "2"` and source the script, do you see the error message bracketed by `1` and `2`?

Comment: @markp-fuso the system echos back 1 but displays the if:Expression syntax immediately. 16 lines is all that is in .profile

Comment: Please add `~/.profile` to your question. No links.

Comment: the code (from the link) looks ok, and runs ok in my `bash` environment; assuming you're running under `bash`, and your file is an exact copy of that code in the link, I'm drawing a blank

Comment: @markp-fuso I have an input line in the form link:directory/to/.profile> and I've been writing the command source ~/.profile here. I've run the command bash and got an input line bash-4.2$ and ran source ~/.profile and the next line was just bash-4.2$. I guess it worked? Sorry I'm quite new to linux

Comment: if you ran: `bash`(this invokes a new `bash` shell) followed by `source ./.profile` and received no error, then that would seem to imply (to me) that your default shell is not `bash`; what is the line from `/etc/passwd` for your linux login? (the last entry in the line should show your default shell, eg, `/usr/bin/bash` or `/bin/csh`, etc)

Comment: @markp-fuso I typed in the command echo $SHELL and got /bin/tcsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the link looks 'ok', runs 'ok' in my `bash` environment, and checks out as 'ok' @ [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

From OP's comments the following does **not** generate a syntax error:

```
$ bash
$ source ./.profile
$                         <<<=== no error message, just a command prompt
```

This confirms the contents of the OP's `.profile` is 'ok' for a `bash` environment.

From additional comments we're told:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
```

Herein lies the issue ... `tcsh` is not the same as `bash`, which also means some of the commands in the OP's `.profile` are invalid when executed under the `tcsh` shell.

We can confirm this if we go out to [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#), scroll down and choose `tcsh`, enter the following code ...

```
tty -s
if test $? = 0
then
    stty dec crt
fi
```

... and when we run the code we get:

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

To get around this syntax issue there are a couple options:

- the OP can get the default shell switched to `bash` (see `chsh` or have the sysadmin update `/etc/passwd` to replace the `tcsh` shell with the `bash` shell); once this is accomplished all new login/shell sessions should have no problems sourcing the OP's `.profile`
- or ...
- the OP can manually run `bash` at the command line and then manually source the `.profile`

Comment: Or, the OP can use the correct configuration file for `tcsh`.